# MVC page that displays multiple, related, ViewModels updating with ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, mvvm, viewmodel

I have some simple list management pages, each is strongly typed against the following ViewModel

```
public class ListManagementIndexViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have Views for Category, Priority, Status and a few other drop downs, there's some AutoMapper configuration that ensures the `Name` property is bound to whatever the Domain model might have for the entity. The idea is that the systems administrators are able to manage what's in these lists (Create new, Edit existing and Delete). This gives me an Index view for each like this:

[image: Priority list management]

I would like to put all of these on a single page, rather than have separate views for each. <strike>I *think* `partials` are *probably* the way to do this, but I'm not clear whether that's a recommended approach or not?</strike>

Also I'm not clear on how to handle the Controller(s). As things stand; with the PriorityController I have the following Index `ActionResult`

```cs
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page)
    {
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
            searchString = currentFilter;

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

        var query = Session.QueryOver<Priority>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
            query.WhereRestrictionOn(p => p.PriorityName)
                 .IsInsensitiveLike(String.Format("%{0}%", searchString));

        var result = query.OrderBy(p => p.PriorityName).Asc.List();

        var viewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Priority>, 
                          IEnumerable<ListManagementIndexViewModel>>(result)
                                  .ToPagedList(pageNumber, PageSize);

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

While I *could* move that to a <strike>'Master'</strike> single list management page I would also need to do the same for the other list types, but then what would my ViewModel need to look like, there are currently 5 lists to manage, so I have 5 controllers doing exactly the same thing, only the types vary. If I were to put all that on 1 <strike>'Master'</strike> single view page I would somehow need to stuff all 5 PagedList collections into 1 ViewModel and then in the <strike>'Master'</strike> single version pass the data off to the relevant <strike>`Partials`</strike> razor code?

Also how would I handle the other Controller actions (Edit, Create and Delete)?

**Update**
Thinking on my feet - if the unified / single view page ViewModel were:

```
public class ListManagementIndexViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, IPagedList<T>> ManagementLists { get; set; }
}
```

and the SinglePageController were

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page)
{
    var priorities = GetPriorities(searchString, currentFilter, page);
    var categories = GetCategories(searchString, currentFilter, page);

    Dictionary<string, IPagedList> viewModel
       = new Dictionary<string, IPagedList<T>>();

    viewModel.Add("Priorities", priorities);
    viewModel.Add("Categories", categories);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

I could move the existing logic out to a private method

```
private IPagedList<Priority> GetPriorities(string searchString, 
                                           string currentFilter, int? page) 
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        searchString = currentFilter;

    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

    var query = Session.QueryOver<Priority>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
        query.WhereRestrictionOn(p => p.PriorityName)
             .IsInsensitiveLike(String.Format("%{0}%", searchString));

    var result = query.OrderBy(p => p.PriorityName).Asc.List();

    var priorities = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Priority>, 
                          IEnumerable<ListManagementIndexViewModel>>(result)
                                  .ToPagedList(pageNumber, PageSize);

    return priorities;
}
```

Then in my View the model would contain the `ManagementLists` collections and I could `foreach` the results into html tables as I'm currently doing but on separate pages.

However a paging through the results would then result in all lists tables paging rather than just the Priorities table. How would I make each update with Ajax, so paging in one table would only update the list in that one table? If I were to re-include searching, which is currently in the ActionResult method, but not implemented in the UI that would also need to update just the Priorities table. For example if I entered "High" in the search for Priority I would only want to query the Priority table and update it and not run 5 queries to the database to search for "High" in Category or any of the other lists.

Comment: I think by **master** page you mean layout. in that case use partials with child actions

Comment: At present I've got 5 Index Views (1 for each type), but I'd like to have all the list management done on one page, the UI would feel smoother. So in my screenshot float 4 more tables to the right of the one already there. It's not a master page as such (in the ASP.NET sense of the word).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should only use a partial **if you intend to use it again**. I see too often people creating them to help break down the code, but they're never used again.

It would be more organised to have the 5 lists under the one page, that way they're all in the one model and are *centrally managed* by one controller/model.

Comment: I have no intention of ever using these again, so partial doesn't sound like the right approach.  But you are spot on with what I want to achieve, the 5 lists on one page (that I've called a master).

Comment: @SimonMartin Don't use the terminology **master** though, people take that as being the **actual** master (the _Layout.cshtml file because technically speaking, that is the MVC equivalent of the master page).

Comment: I have updated the question and removed references to **master** and partial.